# Kernel of canonical morphism in inductive limit (proof by induction)

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, induction

Let $\langle I, \leqslant \rangle$ be a directed poset and $\langle M_i, \mu_{i,j} \rangle$ be a directed system of $A$-modules over $I$. Now let
$$
   C = \bigoplus\limits_{i \in I} M_{i},
$$
and $D$ be a submodule of $C$ generated by $x_{i} - \mu_{i,j}(x_{i})$, $x_{i} \in M_i$, $i \leqslant j$. Then by definition $M = C / D$ is an underlying set of the inductive limit of system $\langle M_i, \mu_{i,j} \rangle$ and if $\mu \colon C \to M$ is a projection, then $\mu_{j} = \mu|_{M_j}$ are canonical morphisms. I want to show that if $\mu_{i}(x_i) = 0$ then there exists $j \geqslant i$ such that $\mu_{i,j}(x_i)=0$ by induction [(here one can find some other proofs)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42286/16273).

If $\mu_{i}(x_i)=0$ then $x_{i} \in M_i \cap D$ so that 
$$
   x_i = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k (y_{i_k} - \mu_{i_k, j_k}(y_{i_k})),
$$
where $y_{i_k} \in M_{i_k}$ and without loss of generality $i_k < j_k$. I'm trying to use induction by number of summands $n$. If $n=1$ then 
$$
   x_i = y_{i_1} - \mu_{i_1,j_1}(y_{i_1}).
$$
If $i \neq i_1$ then $x_i = 0$ because $x_i \in M_i$ and hence $y_{i_1} = 0$. If $i=i_1$ then $x_i = y_{i_1}$ and since $x_i \in M_i$ we have $\mu_{i_1,j_1}(y_{i_1})=\mu_{i_1,j_1}(x_{i})=0$. I have a problem with induction step. I tried to consider maximal and minimal indices $j_k$ and $i_k$ but without success. Please help me to do this.

Comment: Why so complicated? Verify that $C$ verifies the universal property of the directed colimit, hence is isomorphic to the more simple construction of directed colimit (taking the disjoint union of the $M_i$ modulo some equivalence relation), where the property is clear by definition.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I tried to do it via universal property but if I'm not mistaken I must use the property from the question to show that the above construction satisfies the universal property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, this is simple to prove without induction. Suppose that
$$
   x_i = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k (y_{i_k} - \mu_{i_k, j_k}(y_{i_k}))\qquad \text{holds in } C. \ \ \ (*)
$$
Let $T:=\{i,i_1,j_1,\dots,i_n,j_n\}\subseteq I$.
Since $\langle I, \leqslant \rangle$ is directed, there is some $q\in I$ such that $q\ge r$ for all $r\in T$.   Now, both sides of $(*)$ are in the submodule $\oplus_{r\in T} M_r$ of $C$.  Let $$\Psi: \bigoplus_{r\in T} M_r\to M_q$$ be the homomorphism which acts as $\mu_{r,q}$ on each summand $M_r$.  Then applying $\Psi$ to both sides of $(*)$ gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu_{i,q}(x_i)&=&\sum_{k=1}^n a_k (\mu_{i_k,q}(y_{i_k})-\mu_{j_k,q}(\mu_{i_k,j_k}(y_{i_k})))\\
&=&\sum_{k=1}^n a_k (\mu_{i_k,q}(y_{i_k})-\mu_{i_k,q}(y_{i_k}))\\
&=&0.
\end{eqnarray*}