# Generalizing a statement about direct limits in the category of $A$-modules to other categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

The original problem is from Atiyah and Macdonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*, Ex 2.15:

> Suppose $(M_\alpha,\mu_{\beta\gamma})$ is a direct system of modules over a unital commutative ring $A$, $M=\varinjlim M_\alpha$, and $\mu_\alpha\colon M_\alpha\to M$ are natural maps. Given that $\mu_\alpha(x_\alpha)=0$, then there exists $\beta\ge\alpha$ such that $\mu_{\alpha\beta}(x_\alpha)=0$.

Also see: [Does the following property of the direct limit of a direct system follow from the axioms for a direct limit?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42286/23875)

Since I don't know category theory, maybe this one is a baby question. I wonder whether the statement could be generalized, for example, in abelian categories instead of the category of modules? I did try only to make use of universal mapping property to characterize the direct limit, but failed. The question should be a restricted version of usergen's question.

Any idea?

Comment: In a general abelian category, you do not have elements, so you need to decide what you want to be true :-)

Comment: If you can come up with a nicely categorical formulation of your question (i.e. one that doesn't refer explicitly to elements), then a proof in the case of $A$-modules for arbitrary, not necessarily commutative, $A$ implies the result for all abelian categories. This is a direct result of [Mitchell's Embedding Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitchell%27s_embedding_theorem).

Comment: @dorebell No. The embedding does not preserve direct limits in general, so you can't use the embedding theorem to say anything about direct limits.

Comment: The question is closely related to the notions of generalized elements and compact objects.

Comment: Think about what happens in ugly Abelian categories such as the opposite of a module category.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks for clarifying. I haven't used the theorem in practice, but I assumed incorrectly that it would automatically preserve limits. Do you know if the embedding is required to preserve any specific limits?

Comment: The embedding is guaranteed to be fully faithful and preserve finite limits and finite colimits (in particular, kernels, cokernels, and finite direct sums), which is enough to establish many of the basic lemmas of homological algebra.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Now I read from Ravi Vakil's [lecture notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/), Jan 29 2015 draft **1.4.8. Summary** that, in a category where the objects are *set-like*, an element of a colimit can be thought of an element of a single object in the diagram. How can we formalize *set-likeness*? It seems to me that it's a compatibility between limit/colimit and forgetful functor to sets. Is there any generalization?