# A question to Weibel’s IHA lemma 2.6.14 Part 2

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

> Let $I$ be a filtered category and $A:I\longrightarrow Mod-R$ a functor.
>   Then
>
> 1. Every element $a\in \underset{\rightarrow}{\operatorname{Colim}} (A_i)$ is the image of some element $a_i\in A_i$ (for some $i\in I$) under the canonical map $A_i\longrightarrow \underset{\rightarrow}{\operatorname{Colim}}(A_i)$.
> 2. For every $i$, the kernel of the canonical map $A_i\longrightarrow \underset{\rightarrow}{\operatorname{Colim}} (A_i)$ is the union of the kernels of the map $\varphi:A_i\longrightarrow A_j$ (where $\varphi:i\longrightarrow j$ is a map in $I$)

There is above lemma in Weibel’s introduction to homological algebra section 6,chapter 2. I can’t understand the proof of Part 2. Mainly after he said

> we may assume $i=t$.

I can’t understand him.[image]

Comment: A bit of search led me to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42286/), and then to Lemma 5.30 of Rotman’s book *Introduction to Homological Algebra*. His proof, which is essentially the same as Weibel’s, explains a lot of details omitted here.